# Comparison between Appium, Instruments, MonkeyTalk for testing iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, appium, monkeytalk

How can we compare the 3 tools for testing iOS? Which among these will be better for unit testing for developers and regular testing for testers?

Comment: MonkeyTalk is being acquired by Oracle. I don't believe that they will maintain the project, especially not the iOS agent. There are a lot of issues, using the latest MonkeyTalk release (December 2014) with iOS9+. So I recommend to look for another testing framework.

Answer (score 0):

Instruments and the UIAutomation framework is being deprecated in favor of the new XCUITest framework bundled in Xcode 7.